# URL in JSON-LD Schema.org

Tags: microdata, json-ld

I have JSON-LD Schema in the `<head>` of my site which is applied to every page on the site. One of the fields is `url`, i.e.:

```
"url": "http://example.com"
```

Should the URL be the domain of the site, regardless of the page OR should it be the page’s URL?

Note: The schema is for a `LocalBusiness`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m assuming you are using the vocabulary Schema.org and have something like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "url": "http://example.com/"
}
</script>
```

Here the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) belongs to the [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) item. So it should give the URI of the local business, no matter on which page you specify this markup.

This can be the URI of the official website, but you could also decide [to have separate URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669) for the website and for the business (representing the actual thing, not something *about* this thing).